# How to set up 'httpOnly' and 'secure' cookie options with react-cookie-consent?

Tags: security, httponly, react-cookie-consent

My website is running under HTTPS and I try to save the react-cookie-consent cookie as 'httpOnly' and 'secure'. What I tried so far, without success, was **cookieSecurity** and **extraCookieOptions** like this:

```
<CookieConsent
 location="bottom"
 buttonText="I understand"
 cookieSecurity={true}
 extraCookieOptions={{
   httpOnly: true,
   secure: true
 }}>
 This website uses cookies to enhance the user experience.
</CookieConsent>
```

Here is the NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie-consent

Do I miss something in documentation?

Comment: httpOnly cookies are not accessible from the browser scripts by design.

Comment: Thank you, and how to set it up 'secure'? Is this a correct syntax for the package?

Comment: From their documentation it seems that `cookieSecurity={true}` is the right way to do it. I don't think you need `extraCookieOptions`, but unfortunately it is not well documented.